# When will the help center info be filled in?

Tags: discussion

When will the help center contain information relevant to this site specifically, or does it already and I just can't find it?

Comment: My guess is that it will be filled once we get first set of mods, I might be wrong.

Comment: We, as a community, need to decide what **is** off-topic before we can fill it in. I think the best way to do this is to just let people close things they see as off-topic and look in 3-4 weeks to see patterns.

Answer (score 4):

Some help center information can be edited by moderators. Since we do not currently have moderators (and won't until we're public), it can only be edited by staff I believe.

It would be good to bring this up again once we have moderators or bring up another Meta post asking what ***should*** go in the help center.

Answer (score 3):

That is a part of our job on meta to discuss the exact wordings we want to have in the help center and which questions we want on the tour page et cetera.

If we in the private beta have more precisely defined the scope we can fill the help center and the tour page with exactly that information.

Comment: I suggest we split discussions about help center wordings along some natural lines, e.g. discuss on-topic here: http://meta.iot.stackexchange.com/questions/35/what-topics-can-i-ask-about-here and so on

Comment: @Ghanima of course, I was just commenting on the general way forward :)

Comment: yes, and I am completely with you ;)